# How to create a boxplot in RStudio using only min, max, median, lower fourth, upper fourth, and outliers?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a boxplot, but the only data I know is the min, max, median, lower fourth, upper fourth, and the outliers.
This is my data:

- Min: 188.1
- Max: 230.5
- Lower Fourth: 196.0
- Median: 202.2
- Upper Fourth: 216.8
- Outliers: 125.8, 250.2

I have been able to create the boxplot with:

```
dat<-read.table(text = "188.1 196.0 202.2 216.8 230.5")
dat<-t(dat)
bxp(list(stats=dat, n=rep(10, ncol(dat))))
```

But I don't know how to give it the outliers and make it show them. I've only found questions asking how to get rid of the outliers, but I need to know how to show them. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someting like this?

```
dat<-read.table(text = "188.1 196.0 202.2 216.8 230.5")
dat<-t(dat)

xp <- 30
plot(0, type = 'n', ylim=range(dat[,1]) + c(-xp, xp))
bxp(list(stats=dat, n=rep(10, ncol(dat))), add = TRUE)

outliers <- c(250, 160)
points(rep(1, length(outliers)), outliers)
```

Basically just add it as a secondary plot with a range that accounts for the outliers. I just put xp and as a winpw expanding variable but you can change ylim = range(outliers)

Answer (score 3):

Just add additional arguments `out` and `groups` to the list of stats summaries you pass into `bxp()`:

```
bxp(list(stats = dat, n = rep(10, ncol(dat)),
         out = c(125.8, 250.2), groups = c(1,1)))
```

[image]

---

To see how you might have learned that yourself, check out `?bxp`, which includes this description of its first argument:

```
z: a list containing data summaries to be used in constructing
   the plots.  These are usually the result of a call to
   ‘boxplot’, but can be generated in any fashion.
```

Hmm. That looks promising. To learn more about exactly what sort of data summaries result from a call to `boxplot()`, we can check out the `"Value"` section `?boxplot`, where we find that it returns a list with the following components (among others):

```
  out: the values of any data points which lie beyond the extremes
       of the whiskers.

group: a vector of the same length as ‘out’ whose elements indicate
       to which group the outlier belongs.
```